# Problems updating Craft CMS form 3.7.45.1 to 3.7.55.2

Tags: craft3, plugins, manual-updates

I have been trying to update Craft CMS getting the same error messages no matter if I try the CMS panel or the command line (see error messages below). I review the server permission everything seems to be correct; please, how I fix this to complete the update?

Error: Could not delete /var/www/disa/Craft-3.6.15/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-shell/CHANGELOG.md: unlink(/var/www/disa/Craft-3.6.15/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-shell/CHANGELOG.md): Permission denied

Composer output: Loading composer repositories with package information
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Updating dependencies
Lock file operations: 1 install, 92 updates, 2 removals

- Removing fruitstudios/linkit (1.1.12.1)
- Removing true/punycode (v2.1.1)
- Upgrading cebe/markdown (1.2.1 9bac5e9 => 1.2.1)
- Upgrading composer/ca-bundle (1.3.3 30897ed => 1.3.3)
- Upgrading composer/composer (2.2.12 => 2.2.15)
- Upgrading composer/metadata-minifier (1.0.0 c549d23 => 1.0.0)
- Upgrading composer/pcre (1.0.1 67a32d7 => 1.0.1)
- Upgrading composer/semver (3.3.2 3953f23 => 3.3.2)
- Upgrading composer/spdx-licenses (1.5.7 c848241 => 1.5.7)
- Upgrading composer/xdebug-handler (3.0.3 ced2996 => 3.0.3)
- Upgrading craftcms/cms (3.7.45.2 => 3.7.55.2)
- Upgrading craftcms/oauth2-craftid (1.0.0.1 3f18364 => 1.0.0.1)
- Upgrading craftcms/plugin-installer (1.5.7 23ec472 => 1.5.7)
- Upgrading craftcms/server-check (1.2.4 04518e6 => 1.2.4)
- Upgrading creocoder/yii2-nested-sets (0.9.0 cb8635a => 0.9.0)
- Upgrading davechild/textstatistics (1.0.2 dd16252 => 1.0.2)
- Upgrading defuse/php-encryption (v2.3.1 7788048 => v2.3.1)
- Upgrading doctrine/lexer (1.2.3 c268e88 => 1.2.3)
- Upgrading egulias/email-validator (3.2.1 f88dcf4 => 3.2.1)
- Upgrading elvanto/litemoji (3.0.1 acd6fd9 => 3.0.1)
- Upgrading enshrined/svg-sanitize (0.15.4 e50b83a => 0.15.4)
- Upgrading ezyang/htmlpurifier (v4.14.0 => v4.16.0)
- Upgrading froala/craft-froala-wysiwyg (4.0.12 => 4.0.14)
- Upgrading froala/wysiwyg-editor (v4.0.12 => v4.0.14)
- Upgrading guzzlehttp/guzzle (7.5.0 b50a2a1 => 7.5.0)
- Upgrading guzzlehttp/promises (1.5.2 b94b280 => 1.5.2)
- Upgrading guzzlehttp/psr7 (2.4.1 69568e4 => 2.4.1)
- Upgrading justinrainbow/json-schema (5.2.12 ad87d5a => 5.2.12)
- Upgrading laminas/laminas-escaper (2.6.1 25f2a05 => 2.6.1)
- Upgrading laminas/laminas-feed (2.12.3 3c91415 => 2.12.3)
- Upgrading laminas/laminas-stdlib (3.2.1 2b18347 => 3.2.1)
- Upgrading laminas/laminas-zendframework-bridge (1.1.1 6ede705 => 1.1.1)
- Upgrading league/flysystem (1.1.9 094defd => 1.1.9)
- Upgrading league/mime-type-detection (1.11.0 ff6248e => 1.11.0)
- Upgrading league/oauth2-client (2.6.1 2334c24 => 2.6.1)
- Upgrading mikehaertl/php-shellcommand (1.6.4 3488d78 => 1.6.4)
- Upgrading nystudio107/craft-plugin-manifest (1.0.10 d94d147 => 1.0.10)
- Upgrading nystudio107/craft-seomatic (3.4.36 => 3.4.38)
- Upgrading nystudio107/craft-twigfield (1.0.11 1b920b9 => 1.0.11)
- Upgrading paragonie/random_compat (v9.99.100 996434e => v9.99.100)
- Upgrading php-science/textrank (1.2.2 c5ccfc9 => 1.2.2)
- Upgrading phpdocumentor/reflection-common (2.2.0 1d01c49 => 2.2.0)
- Upgrading phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock (5.3.0 622548b => 5.3.0)
- Upgrading phpdocumentor/type-resolver (1.6.1 77a3251 => 1.6.1)
- Upgrading pixelandtonic/imagine (1.2.4.2 5ee4b6a => 1.2.4.2)
- Locking presseddigital/linkit (3.0.2)
- Upgrading psr/container (1.1.1 8622567 => 1.1.1)
- Upgrading psr/http-client (1.0.1 2dfb5f6 => 1.0.1)
- Upgrading psr/http-factory (1.0.1 12ac7fc => 1.0.1)
- Upgrading psr/http-message (1.0.1 f6561bf => 1.0.1)
- Upgrading psr/log (1.1.4 d49695b => 1.1.4)
- Upgrading ralouphie/getallheaders (3.0.3 120b605 => 3.0.3)
- Upgrading react/promise (v2.9.0 234f8fd => v2.9.0)
- Upgrading seld/cli-prompt (1.0.4 b8dfcf0 => 1.0.4)
- Upgrading seld/jsonlint (1.9.0 4211420 => 1.9.0)
- Upgrading seld/phar-utils (1.2.1 ea2f401 => 1.2.1)
- Upgrading sunra/php-simple-html-dom-parser (v1.5.2 75b9b1c => v1.5.2)
- Upgrading swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v6.3.0 8a5d507 => v6.3.0)
- Upgrading symfony/console (v5.4.12 c072aa8 => v5.4.12)
- Upgrading symfony/deprecation-contracts (v2.5.2 e8b495e => v2.5.2)
- Upgrading symfony/filesystem (v5.4.12 2d67c1f => v5.4.12)
- Upgrading symfony/finder (v5.4.11 7872a66 => v5.4.11)
- Upgrading symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.26.0 6fd1b9a => v1.26.0)
- Upgrading symfony/polyfill-iconv (v1.26.0 143f188 => v1.26.0)
- Upgrading symfony/polyfill-intl-grapheme (v1.26.0 433d055 => v1.26.0)
- Upgrading symfony/polyfill-intl-idn (v1.26.0 59a8d27 => v1.26.0)
- Upgrading symfony/polyfill-intl-normalizer (v1.26.0 219aa36 => v1.26.0)
- Upgrading symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.26.0 9344f9c => v1.26.0)
- Upgrading symfony/polyfill-php72 (v1.26.0 bf44a9f => v1.26.0)
- Upgrading symfony/polyfill-php73 (v1.26.0 e440d35 => v1.26.0)
- Upgrading symfony/polyfill-php80 (v1.26.0 cfa0ae9 => v1.26.0)
- Upgrading symfony/process (v5.4.11 6e75fe6 => v5.4.11)
- Upgrading symfony/service-contracts (v2.5.2 4b426aa => v2.5.2)
- Upgrading symfony/string (v5.4.12 2fc515e => v5.4.12)
- Upgrading symfony/yaml (v5.4.12 7a3aa21 => v5.4.12)
- Upgrading twig/twig (v2.14.13 66856cd => v2.14.13)
- Upgrading verbb/base (1.0.4 71cee53 => 1.0.4)
- Upgrading verbb/navigation (1.4.26 => 1.4.28)
- Upgrading verbb/super-table (2.7.2 => 2.7.3)
- Upgrading verbb/tablemaker (3.0.1 => 3.0.4)
- Upgrading voku/anti-xss (4.1.39 64a59ba => 4.1.39)
- Upgrading voku/arrayy (7.9.4 4a99593 => 7.9.4)
- Upgrading voku/email-check (3.1.0 6ea8429 => 3.1.0)
- Upgrading voku/portable-ascii (2.0.1 b56450e => 2.0.1)
- Upgrading voku/portable-utf8 (6.0.9 eb2861c => 6.0.9)
- Upgrading voku/stop-words (2.0.1 8e63c0a => 2.0.1)
- Upgrading voku/stringy (6.5.3 c453c88 => 6.5.3)
- Upgrading voku/urlify (5.0.7 014b207 => 5.0.7)
- Upgrading webmozart/assert (1.11.0 11cb219 => 1.11.0)
- Upgrading webonyx/graphql-php (v14.11.6 => v14.11.8)
- Upgrading yiisoft/yii2 (2.0.45 e2223d4 => 2.0.45)
- Upgrading yiisoft/yii2-composer (2.0.10 94bb3f6 => 2.0.10)
- Upgrading yiisoft/yii2-debug (2.1.21 fa9fa02 => 2.1.21)
- Upgrading yiisoft/yii2-queue (2.3.4 ed30b5f => 2.3.4)
- Upgrading yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer (2.1.3 7b7ec87 => 2.1.3)
  Writing lock file
  Installing dependencies from lock file
  Package operations: 0 installs, 0 updates, 4 removals
- Removing yiisoft/yii2-shell (2.0.5)
- Removing symfony/var-dumper (v5.4.11)
- Removing psy/psysh (v0.11.8)
- Removing nikic/php-parser (v4.15.1)
  Uninstall of yiisoft/yii2-shell failed
  Uninstall of symfony/var-dumper failed
  Uninstall of psy/psysh failed
  Uninstall of nikic/php-parser failed

Comment: Firstly, type `whoami` - copy & pase output and then `ls -ld /var/www/disa/Craft-3.6.15/vendor/` - copy & paste output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gave a slightly confusing description

What is in the screenshot is not an error, but a warning that the package is outdated and it is better to get rid of it

The errors you are throwing are due to permission issues, or the user has insufficient permissions for the folder or the folder has incorrect permissions (for example, the `craftcmsfolder/vendor` is not writable).

In addition, in the paths you specify folders in which a completely different version of the craft is indicated, you are sure. are you updating the correct site?